# Regex Rewrites stop at hyphen but allow hyphen in the string (.htaccess)

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

`RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-((foot|basket)(ball))-schedule(/)?$ /yearschedule.php?sport=$3&school=$1&year=$2&schedule=true [NC,L]`  is the current code.

I goofed and didn't realize the basketball schedules would also include a hyphen.  How would I change this code to allow the rewrites to recognize the basketball page years correctly?

Doesn't work correctly

```
http://domain.com/michigan-1999-00-basketball-schedule
```

Works Correctly

```
http://domain.com/michigan-1999-football-schedule
```

The problem is that the rewrite doesn't recognize the format because in the eyes of the server, it stops the basketball years at 1999-|here|00 instead of following through.  I'm really not sure what code I should use to fix this.

(regex novice)

Comment: 00 could be any two digit integer

Comment: `\d+-basket` would do but if the 00 is representing a month and u need it or want to exclude it you should go for something like: `^([^-]*)-([^-]*)(-\d+|-)((foot|basket)(ball))-schedule(/)?$`

Comment: As in RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-(foot|basket|\d{1,2}-basket)])-((foot|basket)(ball))-schedule(/)?$ /yearschedule.php?sport=$3&school=$1&year=$2&schedule=true [NC,L]   ?

Comment: It's not representing a month - it's representing two years - 1999-00 would represent the 1999-2000 season

Answer (score 1):

Try this line instead:

```
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-((foot|(?:[^-]*-)?basket)(ball))-schedule/?$ /yearschedule.php?sport=$3&school=$1&year=$2&schedule=true [NC,L]
```

It will match following:

- `http://domain.com/michigan-1999-00-basketball-schedule`
- `http://domain.com/michigan-1999-basketball-schedule`
- `http://domain.com/michigan-1999-football-schedule`